# Why is this not working python csv files

Tags: python

```
import csv

DATA=((10, 'Record 1', 'hi'),
      (20, 'Record 2', 'bye'),
      (30, 'Record 3', 'test'))

f=open('bookdata.csv', 'w')
writer=csv.writer(f)
writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for record in DATA:
    writer.writerow(record)
f.close()


f=open('bookdata.csv', 'r')

reader=csv.reader(f)
for chap, title, pack in reader:
    print("%s, %s, %s" % (chap, title, pack))
f.close()
```

It looks right to me but it says 
"ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack"

It does read the first line tho, it's after reading that one that it crashes...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Record should be list.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default delimiter for CSV is a comma, but you are using tabs. As you haven't told the reader to use the tab character, it is using a comma when reading fields.

Since there is no comma in your CSV file; the lines are not being split up; and each loop over `reader` is returning a list with only one string:

```
['10\t"Record 1"\t"hi"']
['20\t"Record 2"\t"bye"']
['30\t"Record 3"\t"test"']
```

So when you try to unpack this, you get the error.

To fix the problem, tell the reader what delimiter you are using:

```
reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
```

You should also use the [`with statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), which will automatically close the files for you, and `writerows` to write out all your items at once:

```
import csv

DATA=((10, 'Record 1', 'hi'),
      (20, 'Record 2', 'bye'),
      (30, 'Record 3', 'test'))

with open('bookdata.csv', 'w') as f:
    # writer=csv.writer(f) - this line is not required
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(DATA) # note here I am using writerows

with open('bookdata.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for chap, title, pack in reader:
        print("%s, %s, %s" % (chap, title, pack))
```

Comment: Same error "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack" :/

Comment: Well I got python 3.3 and is not working but I guess if it works for you, it will work for my test tomorrow thanks lol

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
import csv

DATA= [[10, 'Record 1', 'hi'],
        [20, 'Record 2', 'bye'],
        [30, 'Record 3', 'test'] ]

f=open('bookdata.csv', 'w')
writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for record in DATA:
    writer.writerow(record)
f.close()

f=open('bookdata.csv', 'r')

reader=csv.reader(f)
for chap, title, pack in reader:
    print("%s, %s, %s" % (chap, title, pack))
f.close()
```